# symfony sfGuardPlugin Error Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in plugins/sfGuardPlugin/lib/user/sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php

Tags: symfony1

I am trying to install **sfGuard Plugin** with symfony 1.4 (Propel).
I was some how able to install it and it worked fine (I was able to register, login and logout).

But once i cleared my cache again, i am not able to login and I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   plugins/sfGuardPlugin/lib/user/sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php on line
>   81, referer: http://localhost/index.php/login

I am not sure what i did wrong, but somehow i cant get it to work again. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin. but same error.

I've modified my **app.yml**, **settings.yml**, **routing.yml**, as per the documentation. I've also modified `apps/myapp/lib/myUser.class.php` to extend from **sfGuardSecurityUser**.

The form submit enters the file `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php` and fails after `form->isValid` on the `$this->getUser()->signIn($values['user'],...)` function call.

I verified that `$values['user']` has the correct value from the form. The signIn function in turn calls: `$this->setAttribute('user_id', $user->getId(), 'sfGuardSecurityUser');`
and thats where its not able to get `$user` as an object, its still the "username" i passed in the form.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I verified that $values['user'] has the correct value from the form.

What exactly are you thinking the correct value should be? It sounds like you created your own form and are expecting the `user` field to be the username, when in fact its expecting `user` to be an array like:

```
$user = Array (
   'username' => 'Username value from form',
   'password' => 'password value from form'
}
```

In essence your form should look something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user[username]" />
  <input type="password" id="password" name="user[password]" />
</form>
```

Comment: no, i did not create my own form, I am using the sfGuardFormSignin that comes with the plugin. and the code that i was referring to (where it fails), $values['user'] is also part of the plugin, i did not modify that.

Comment: here's the plugin code i am referring to: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php line 45

Answer (score 0):

after some debugging and starting from scratch, looks like i had screwed up in overwriting the default sfGuardFormSignin.class.php , which made the $user class invalid and so any function calls on it was failing.